# Parameterized Constructor Error

Tags: java

I am having a error in my program. It is located in the parameterized constructor shown here.

```
public class Student {
// instance variables
private String studentId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double [] grades;


/** 
 * default constructor
 * the id, first and last names are initialized to "none"
 * the array is instantiated to store 4 elements - each element is
 * initialized to -1.0
 */
public Student()
{
    studentId = "none";
    firstName = "none";
    lastName = "none";
    grades = new double [4];
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = -1.0;
    }
}

/** 
 * parameterized constructor
 * stores the parameters into the appropriate instance variables
 * @param sId the value to be stored in the instance variable studentId
 * @param sFirstName the value to be stored in the instance variable firstName
 * @param sLastName the value to be stored in the instance variable lastName
 * @param sExams the address of the array whose values will be copied into the 
 * instance variable grades
 */
public Student(String sId , String sFirstName , String sLastName , double[] sExams )
{
    studentId = sId;
    firstName = sFirstName;
    lastName = sLastName;
    sExams = new double[grades.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = sExams[i];
    }




}

/**
 * setStudentId - mutator method for studentId
 * stores the parameter into the instance variable
 * @param sId the value to be stored in the instance variable studentId
 */
public void setStudentId(String sId)
{
    this.studentId = sId;
}

/**
 * setGrades - mutator method for grades
 * stores the parameter into the instance variable
 * @param sExams the address of the array whose values will be copied into the 
 * instance variable grades
 */
public void setGrades(double [] sExams)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = sExams[i];
    }
}

/**
 * getStudentId - accessor method for id
 * @return a reference to the instance variable id
 */
public String getStudentId()
{
    return studentId;
}

/**
 * getFirstName - accessor method for firstName
 * @return a reference to the instance variable firstName
 */
public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}


/**
 * getLastName - accessor method for lastName
 * @return a reference to the instance variable lastName
 */
public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

/**
 * getGrades - accessor method for grades
 * @return a reference to a copy of the instance variable grades
 */
public double [] getGrades()
{
    double [] gradesCopy = new double [grades.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        gradesCopy[i] = grades[i];
    }
    return gradesCopy;
}

/**
 * findLowestExam - find the lowest exam score in the array and returns its location 
 * in the array
 * @return the position of the lowest exam grade in the array
 */
public int findLowestExam()
{
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        if(grades[i] < grades[lowestIndex])
            lowestIndex = i;
    }
    return lowestIndex;
}

/**
 * calcExamAverage - calculates the average of the exams in one of two ways 
 * if the parameter is true, the lowest exam score is dropped in 
 * calculating the average
 * if the parameter is false, no exams are dropped in the calculating
 * the average
 * @param drop - a boolean variable to specify whether or not to drop the lowest score
 * @return the average of the exams
 */

public double calcExamAverage(boolean drop)
{
    double sum = 0; 
    double average;
    if(drop == false)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
        {
            sum += grades[i];

        }
        average = sum / grades.length;
        return average;
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
        {
            sum += grades[i];


        }
        average = (sum - grades[this.findLowestExam()]) / (grades.length - 1);
        return average;
    }

}
/**
 * toString - create and return a String with the instance variable values
 * @return a reference to a String containing the id, first and last names
 * and the exam grades
 */
public String toString()
{
    String str = "ID: " + studentId + "\n" + "Name: " + lastName + "," + firstName + "\n" + "Grades:";
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        str += grades[i] + " ";

    }
    return str;





}
```

}

For the most parts of the program, I have gotten it down. However, I skipped the parameterized constructor with the array until I decided to run it. I found out there was a error and returned to see that I did not copy the array properly in the parameterized constructor. I want to know how to proceed on fixing this since I could not find a solution.

Comment: Show the whole class. What is the definition of `grades`, for example?

Comment: @Andre I added the whole class for a clearer picture

Comment: Your edit changed the question, because you removed one of the two bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the following line

```
sExams = new double[grades.length];
```

You are writing over your parameter instead of resizing the grades field. If you change it to

```
grades = new double[sExams.length];
```

Then the grades field will be correctly reallocated to the array size of the sExam param.

Comment: Got an extra space between `sExams` and `length`

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem sure it does.

Comment: @arias_JC Good catch, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following:

```
public Student(String sId , String sFirstName , String sLastName , double[] sGrades )
{
    studentId = sId;
    firstName = sFirstName;
    lastName = sLastName;
    grades = new double[sGrades.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        grades[i] = sGrades[i];
    }
}
```

In other words, you need to initialize `grades` like how you were doing in your default constructor, only using the parameter passed in. In your current parameterized constructor you are trying to set the parameter passed in.

Additionally, you  can set your array as such:

```
grades = sGrades.clone();
// or
System.arraycopy(sGrades, 0, grades , 0, sGrades.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
sExams = new double[grades.length];
```

will destroy the parameter value for sExams. `sExams` is your input parameter. Also, `grades` is not yet created, so `grades.length` will fail on NullPointerException. sExams.length would be okay so long as the caller provides a value for it. You want to create `grades` from `sExams`.